# What is the modern way to play sound data in 'snd ' resource format?

Tags: cocoa, macos

Sound Manager functions such as `SndPlay()` are deprecated and not available in 64-bit. The AudioServices functions are modern but only seem to deal with files and are not [documented](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioConverterFormats/SupportedAudioConverterFormats.html) to handle this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a modern API to play them, perhaps because the format is both quite ancient and complicated, starting out in System 7 and being extended several times since.

What I found written about the 'snd ' resource:

> System sound files are simply type 1
>   'snd ' resources stored with a type of
>   'sfil' and a creator of 'movr'. The
>   Mac OS provides the familiar icon for
>   them and permits playback in the
>   Finder by double-clicking on them. An
>   'snd ' is a type of resource which
>   consists of a series of commands for
>   use by the Sound Manager. In addition
>   to digitized sound samples, 'snd '
>   resources can contain direct
>   frequency-modulated and wave
>   table-based sounds. Any number of the
>   three types can be combined with
>   various effects to produce complex
>   sound files. Simple Beep is an example
>   of a non-digitized 'snd '. There are
>   two types of 'snd ' resources,
>   amazingly called type 1 and type 2.
>   Type 1 is the format described above
>   and is referred to as the System sound
>   format. Type 2 is for use with
>   HyperCard and can contain only a
>   sampled (digitized) sound. SoundApp
>   can play both types but will only
>   convert sampled sounds. For more
>   information on 'snd ' files consult
>   Inside Macintosh VI or Inside
>   Macintosh: Sound. A familiarity with
>   the Resource Manager would also be
>   helpful. 8-bit samples are stored as
>   unsigned bytes, like SoundCap/Edit,
>   but 16-bit samples are signed, like
>   AIFF. Stereo 'snd ' resources are also
>   possible, but Sound Manager 3.0 or
>   later is required to play 16-bit
>   samples directly. The possible types
>   of compression for 'snd ' resources
>   are the same MACE, IMA and µ-law types
>   used in AIFF-C files.

Source: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~franke/SoundApp/formats.html#system7

I would think that your best option is to re-record any such sounds into an intermediate lossless format for archival purposes, and then convert them into the best format for the requirements of your app.

Comment: This is not an option because my app needs to be able to play sounds supplied by the user.

Comment: @MichaelTsai I know this is an old question, but for posterity: Nothing uses system sound files anymore. (This was even mostly true in 2010.) There is no point in trying to support them unless you're specifically working with really old data.

Comment: @duskwuff Agreed. At the time, I had a lot of customers with old files that they wanted to play. They ended up choosing to run my app in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Core Audio is definitely what you want. However, I believe you're mistaken on the Core Audio documentation. The table you linked to includes an entry for "NeXT/Sun Audio (.snd, .au)".

You mention that Core Audio "only seems to deal with files", but this isn't true. You can setup a graph with the source being of type `kAudioUnitType_Generator` and subtype `kAudioUnitSubType_ScheduledSoundPlayer`.

I wrote a [morse code program](http://github.com/nall/morsetrainer) that mixes multiple audio sources that are generated in memory. It might be a useful example. [MTPlayer.m](http://github.com/nall/morsetrainer/blob/master/src/MTPlayer.m) would be a reasonable place to start looking at the code.

Comment: the Classic Mac OS 'snd ' resource format is not the same as the Sun/NeXT sound format with the file extension .snd.

Answer (score -1):

Quattro Pro provided a macro command {Play name.snd} where name was a one of three digital files that came with the program. It was a spreadsheet that ran on 640kb + of RAM. The SND files are approx 5kb in size and last a second or so. Borland (who made Quattro Pro) didn't provide sound editing backup but as this was circa 1992, I guess the files would have been fairly easy to obtain. I still have a working copy of that spreadsheet but no means (yet) to backgrade existing sound files for trialling.

Comment: What you're describing here is a completely different format with the same name.